# How to deploy an Java Enterprise Application to WLS 12c using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, weblogic12c, ear

I have Weblogic 12c Server configured on Eclipse(Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: 2018-09). I have an enterprise application which I'm able to build. But, I'm unable to find an option to deploy same to WLS from Eclipse. I know an enterprise application can be exported as an ear file and then deployed manually. But, isn't there an option to directly deploy to WLS from eclipse?

EDIT: Some option similar to NetBeans wherein one can right click an enterprise application and select deploy option.

Comment: You have to configure your server in Eclipse and then deploy your ear. File / New / Server / etc...

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin  As mentioned, I did configure it in Eclipse and I'm able to start same from Eclipse.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin FYI, I found the solution and posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on a project(which can be deployed on a server like enterprise/EJB/web) and select 'Run As' and then 'Run on Server' option.